# How to listen for an onclick event and then add another onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have carousel banner that is dynamically created and I have no control over the HTML. It generates the below code for each image in the carousel, the only thing that changes is the img id; it goes up by 1.

```
<a href="/somelike.aspx" onclick="window.open(this.href, (this.target? this.target : '_self'));return false;"><img id="theimg1_0" src="someimage.jpg" alt="Slide Show Image" title="" border="0"></a>
```

I need to write some jQuery so when this event is fired:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href, (this.target? this.target : '_self'));
```

I fire this event:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'slider2', 'click', $(this).attr('href'),0,true]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use event delegation, and not worry about changing the existing onclick event.  If you are using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('#carousel').on('click', 'a', function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'slider2', 'click', this.href,0,true]);
});
```

EDIT:

I see now that the original code's onclick handler returns false, screwing up the event delegation.  Try this instead:

```
$('#carousel').on('mousedown', 'a', function(){
    this.onclick = function(e){
        window.open(this.href, (this.target? this.target : '_self'));
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'slider2', 'click', this.href,0,true]);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The mousedown should fire before the onclick event fires, allowing you the opportunity to replace the onclick event handler.

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't work. I think it's because the carousel dynamically changes every couple of seconds so the html changes. I put the click event inside a onload event, should I be doing it a different way?(let me know if you need an example)

Comment: Event delegation is a way of avoiding the changing HTML from being an issue.  I didn't notice before that the onclick event was returning false, so that's is why the delegation isn't working.  The event is stopped from bubbling up the DOM tree, which I would say was a shortsighted move on the carousel's author's part.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference a function as an event handler something like this:

html:

```
<a href="/somelike.aspx" onclick="onClickHandler();"><img id="theimg1_0" src="someimage.jpg" alt="Slide Show Image" title="" border="0"></a>
```

javascript:

```
function onClickHandler(){
    window.open(this.href, (this.target? this.target : '_self'));
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'slider2', 'click', $(this).attr('href'),0,true]);
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the html at all so I can't event add this onclick="onClickHandler();" to the link